# Error - Attempting to do parallel computing without protecting your import on a system that does not support forking.

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am using GridSearchCV in a Jupyter Notebook on a cluster. I have 128 cores that I'd like to use for the gridsearchcv, so i've set n_jobs = -1

Now I get an error, "ImportError: [joblib] Attempting to do parallel computing without protecting your import on a system that does not support forking. To use parallel-computing in a script, you must protect your main loop using "if **name** == '**main**'". Please see the joblib documentation on Parallel for more information"

I have since wrapped my code as suggested so in my Jupyter code chuck but it still gives the same error. How exactly do I apply the " "if name == 'main'" statement in my Jupyter notebook?

Comment: You should post your code. Jupyter is just a runtime environment for your code, the error says you should put your code under `if __name__ ==  "__main__": ...`.  There is nothing to "apply" to your jupyter notebook.  If I had to guess with no context, I'd suspect you're importing a script-like file somewhere as though it were a library or module, when the code in that script should have a `if __name__ == "__main__"` over the executing part of the code.

Comment: Do you have the latest version of joblib installed (0.12.2)? For my conda environment, I found installing that with `conda install joblib` as well as putting my code under `if __name__ == "__main__":` worked. This was directly in Spyder though, not sure about Jupyter Notebook.